# Visual Studio 2013: Error in Regular Expression for Find/Replace

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2013, find

I'm using the following regular expression in the Visual Studio 2013 find/replace dialog to find a namespace reference everywhere in a solution but not where it's referenced by a using statement:

```
(?!using) System.Data.Entity
```

However, I receive tons of results of `using System.Data.Entity` results.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a lookbehind, not a lookahead:

```
(?<!using )System.Data.Entity
```

Your regex looks for a position where the next few characters are not `using`, then it rewinds and tries to match the second condition starting at the same spot: `System.Data.Entity`.  If the second condition is true, you're already past the point where the first condition would matter.

Because the lookbehind looks at the *preceding* characters, it leaves the starting position at the correct position to test the second condition.

Comment: Great, thanks! I forgot: What's the difference? Why doesn't look-ahead return the same result?

Comment: I've added an explanation.  Hope it helps; as with many things regex, true understanding tends to come at its own pace.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for enlightening me on this.